# yii2 how can I access post value

Tags: php, yii2

I have the following code in my controller trying to get it to work before adding validation etc

This code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395410/mailchimp-api-2-0-and-php-subscribe-form) however I will be adapting it anyway

```
    $email = $_POST['Newsletter[email]'];

    $session->save_email($email);
    // Subscribe User to List
    $api_key = new sammaye\mailchimp\Mailchimp(['apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx']);
    $list_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
    $Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $email ) );
```

However I get the following error (Does this mean my most data is in an array newbie)

```
Undefined index: Newsletter[email]
```

Is this something I need to set within my yii2 form so that instead of the name field being Newsletter[email] its just email?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as follows:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $email = $data['NewsLetter']['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As was already stated you can either use `$_POST` or the `request`-object.
That object encompasses everything that enters your application on startup. So yes, `\Yii::$app->request->post()` gives you all incoming POST-data and `\Yii::$app->request->post('name')` will give you a single one. Same with the `get` function.

However given your code that is not how you should be using Yii. The name of your variables suggests that the post is done using a model, so you might want to use that again, makes it a lot easier on validation.

If you don't have the model, it can look like so:

```
class Newsletter extends \yii\base\Model
{
   public $email;

   public function rules()
   {
      return array(
        array('email', 'email', 'skipOnEmpty' => false)
      );
   }
}
```

The actual code in your controller could be more amongst the lines:

```
$request = \Yii::$app->request;
if ($request->isPost) {
   $newsletter = new Newsletter;
   if ($newsletter->load($request->post()) &&  $newsletter->validate()) {
      // do your thing 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means, it is inside an array.

Try to do the following instead :

```
// Using isset will make sure, you don't trigger a Notice (when the variable does not exist)
$email = isset($_POST['Newsletter']['email']) ? $_POST['Newsletter']['email'] : null;

// Make sure you are receiving an email address
if ($email && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $session->save_email($email);
    // Subscribe User to List
    $api_key = new sammaye\mailchimp\Mailchimp(['apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx']);
    $list_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    $Mailchimp = new Mailchimp( $api_key );
    $Mailchimp_Lists = new Mailchimp_Lists( $Mailchimp );
    $subscriber = $Mailchimp_Lists->subscribe( $list_id, array( 'email' => $email ) );
}
// Display an error message ?
else 
{
    // @todo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML form field is as below

```
<input name="Newsletter[email]" type="text">
```

then the code with in controller should be

```
$data = Yii::$app->request->post();
$email= $data['Newsletter']['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The inline solution is:

```
if(is_null($email = Yii::$app->request->post('Newsletter')['email']))
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('newsletter email must set');
```

if so if email isn't set it throws Bad Request and notice that `$_POST` isn't good solution when you are using a PHP framework and it's security isn't provided by framework but `Yii::$app->request->post` is secured by Yii.

Answer (score -1):

You should simply try `$_POST['Newsletter']['email']`.

Comment: he want yii2 style